# AWS Group Inline Policy Limit Access For Specific Resources with Tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have created development group on which I want to impose group inline policy that would allow each member to be able to describe EC2 instances that have a tag with a Key "Product" that has a value equal to "TestProduct".
The below shown example doesn't grant the required access, where if I leave resosurce * it works, so it is something on the way I define it not the credentials or above level.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "XXXX",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/Product": "TestProduct"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The error I receive in aws cli is:
An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ec2:DescribeInstances` command does not support resource-level permissions. This means that you must specify `*` as the `Resource` in the IAM policy statement. If you specify anything other than `*` for `Resource`, then authorization will fail (as you've already seen).

This means that you cannot "hide" instances from certain IAM users. Either an IAM user will see all instances, or none.

Please see the following document for a list of commands that support resource-level permissions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources.html